# Binding form on top of an other including location

Tags: c#, vb.net

I made a media player for me and I needed an overlay and the only way it worked was by creating a form to place on top, I'm using a timer to put the location of the form on the top left location on the media element and it shows when the main form is moving. Is there any way to bind the location of the overlay form?

This is the code from the timer:

```
Private Sub TimerOverlay_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TimerOverlay.Tick
    If OrgPoint <> MediaPlayer.PointToScreen(Point.Empty) Then
        FrmOverlay.Location = MediaPlayer.PointToScreen(Point.Empty)
        OrgPoint = MediaPlayer.PointToScreen(Point.Empty)
    End If
End Sub
```

This is the form:

```
    'LabelMain'

    Me.LabelMain.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(CType(CType(5, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(5, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(5, Byte), Integer))
    Me.LabelMain.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
    Me.LabelMain.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 30.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold)
    Me.LabelMain.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
    Me.LabelMain.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
    Me.LabelMain.Name = "LabelMain"
    Me.LabelMain.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(720, 104)
    Me.LabelMain.TabIndex = 0

    'FrmOverlay'

    Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
    Me.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(720, 104)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.LabelMain)
    Me.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
    Me.Name = "FrmOverlay"
    Me.Opacity = 0.8R
    Me.ShowIcon = False
    Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
    Me.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
    Me.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.Black
```

Comment: Could you share some relevant code snippets?

Comment: @gareththegeek I edited the post, everything I have. The media player I use is vlc using vlc dotnet: https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what's your intention is.. You want to transpose one form on top of another? And then synchronize movement and size changes? Basically, you can add handlers to parent form's SizeChanged and LocationChanged events. But thats not quite the end of it.. This seems to work:

```
public partial class SomeForm : Form
{
    Form overlay;

    public SomeForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.overlay = new Form();
        overlay.Owner = this;
        overlay.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        overlay.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        overlay.BackColor = Color.Blue;

        this.LocationChanged += SomeForm_LocationChanged;
        this.SizeChanged += SomeForm_SizeChanged;
        this.FormClosed += SomeForm_FormClosed;
        this.Load += SomeForm_Load;
    }

    private void SomeForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        overlay.Size = this.ClientSize;
        overlay.Location = this.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
        overlay.Show();
    }

    private void SomeForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        overlay.Close();
    }

    private void SomeForm_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        overlay.Size = this.ClientSize;
    }

    private void SomeForm_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        overlay.Location = this.PointToScreen(new Point(0,0));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm an idiot... this was simple I don't know why I thought it was complicated or why I forgot about the LocationChanged event. Thank you!